# Mysqli Statement returning incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to return the data that is true from my database using this mysqli statement

```
$resulttwo = mysqli_query($link, "
SELECT 
*
FROM
Events 
WHERE 
time >= '%$lasttime%'");
```

The variable "lasttime" is an float of a really high value. The numbers in the database are all below below this number. However, when I use this statement, it returns all rows in the database. I do not understand why using this comparison yields incorrect results. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: What's the type of `time` column? What's the value of `lasttime` that you used?

Comment: time is a string type and the value of last time i used (sent as a string) is 1415143730300 @ekad

Comment: `time` column is a string type? what string type? `VARCHAR`? `TIME`? datatype?. and whats up with the `%` wildcards

Comment: for fun, turn that into `$query = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE time >= '%$lasttime%'"; echo $query; $resulttwo = mysqli_query($link, $query);` instead,  to see why your query's failing. Although you should have done that before posting this question, really.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The query returning what it thinks is correct, I do not think it is creating an error. Im just trying to figure out how the query is "thinking". I believe the error may lie with the fact the the time column is a string type and I am comparing strings using > and <. I am going to attempt to change this to see if there are different results.

Comment: @Ghost it is varchar

Comment: `WHERE time LIKE '%$lasttime%'` or `WHERE time >= '$lasttime'`

Comment: Also, since you're using `MySQLi`, use `WHERE time>=?` instead of stuffing values into query.

Comment: @Passerby what do you mean? I thought I used >=

Comment: @superuserdo You might find this interesting: [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'%$lasttime%'` is a string, that equates to zero when used in a numeric comparison.  `time` may be a string column, as you say, but gets successfully cast numeric when you use `>=`.  if $lasttime equaled 12345 and $time equaled 54321, then the comparison is `54321 >= '%12345%'` which equates to `54321 >= 0`, as `'%12345%'` doesn't get converted to an int.

To test:

```
select '%12345%' = 0, '12345' = 0
```

returns TRUE (because that's a non-numeric string, whose value is 0) and FALSE (because that string can be converted to 12,345, and not equal to 0).

I have no idea why you want to use wildcards in this query.

Comment: Wow, this was a great explanation. Thanks.